# MaterialDesignXAMLToolkit setup not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

I'm trying to setup MaterialDesignXAMLToolkit and I follow the steps but it still does not work. I do not have much experience with WPF and XAML.

This is my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MaterialDesign_TEST.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I have installed the MaterialDesignThemes NuGet and also ShowMeTheXAML as they require in the Getting started guide but it shows me that the Source cannot be found.

[image]

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
```

With:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
```

I had the same problem with the Toolkit and after replacing that line everything started working for me.

Also, double check none of the packages have a yellow warning triangle in the list under Dependencies>Packages.

[image]